# Repeatable git cherry-pick

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

`git cherry-pick` is not idempotent in the sense that commit hash after cherry-picking depends on current time and current user (as commiter).

I'd like to have the idempotence propery, that means twice the sequence:

```
git reset --hard BASE-COMMIT
git cherry-pick INTERESTING-COMMIT
```

and then again:

```
git reset --hard BASE-COMMIT
git cherry-pick INTERESTING-COMMIT
```

results in exactly same commit hash at HEAD both times.

Is there a way to tell git to reuse Committer Name and Committer Date from the original commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the commit date when you check in the cherry-pick.  For example:

```
git reset --hard BASE-COMMIT
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git log -1 --format='%ct' INTERESTING-COMMIT)
git cherry-pick INTERESTING-COMMIT
```

This assumes that the user is stable also, otherwise you will also need to set `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, like this:

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(git log -1 --format='%cn' INTERESTING-COMMIT)
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(git log -1 --format='%ce' INTERESTING-COMMIT)
```